# C# Canvas Intersection between circle and line

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have two shapes line and ellipse(circle). And I want to get point of intersection between them. The line goes straight through the center of circle. Does anybody know methods which can help? I try to find the easiest way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Intersection implies two overlapping areas - a line is not an area?

Comment: I need to find the point which common for this line and the circle.

Comment: Your question is more of a math question than wpf/canvas see [How do I calculate the intersection(s) of a straight line and a circle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228841/how-do-i-calculate-the-intersections-of-a-straight-line-and-a-circle)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I mean any extensions which can help. Like var point = ellipse.IntersectionWith(line). I know how to find this point manually, but I just do not want invent bicycle.